# how to pass object through corresponding element?

Tags: javascript

Lets say i have 4 labels and 4 buttons side by side.
I know i can change the label values based on id with corresponding buttons.
I want to know is there any other ways of doing it, particularly with object or reference?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Set demo1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Set demo2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Set demo3</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
```

Comment: Please add the code you have so far.

Comment: there are 10000 ways to write code. and only 42 is the right answer

Comment: What do you mean by object or reference? You can walk the dom yourself and check for the id yourself, but that seems the same thing that `getElementById` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all of you code to a div and assign an ID to it. Then refer that div in JS. And then by using HTML DOM childNodes Property (Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) for more information ), you can refer to each of the single element of that div.